# How to allow the user to logged in a new fb account while another is logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am using facebook api. I want to fetch user data from facebook. User can add register multiple Facebook accounts at a time.

My problem is:
If the user logged in once in a Facebook account and want to add another account. It do not logged out automatically from the existed account.
I want to logged out the user from existed logged in page and redirect it to the Facebook login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the FB.logout function and then call the FB.login function directly after, e.g.

```
function logout_and_login() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
    FB.login( function() {
      // do something
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can add the function to a button / link as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript api call:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  alert("user is now logged out");
});
```

If you are using the PHP-SDK

```
header("Location: " . $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>"http://domain.com/wheretoredirectafterlogout.html")));
```